# Future and infinite loop in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I want to execute 2 independent infinite loops in scala. The first task takes about 1 second for each run and the second takes 0.5 seconds.

Here is the code:

```
package future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object MyFuture {
  def task1(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("doing job 1")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }

  def task2(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("doing job 2")
    Thread.sleep(500)
  }

  def infiniteLoop(): Future[Unit] = {
    Future.sequence(List(task1(), task2())).flatMap(x => infiniteLoop())
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Await.ready(infiniteLoop(), Duration.Inf)
  }

}
```

The output of the program

```
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
doing job 1
doing job 2
```

I want the output of the job 2 to be twice as the output of job 1 because it takes half the time.

What I can do to simulate 2 real independent process?

Comment: I think Scala cannot make your infinite recursion tail recursive.

Comment: You might achieve what you want by running two separate threads each of which has a loop inside (and can exit on some global flag). What you do now is always launching a pair of tasks and waiting until both complete.

Comment: @ziggystar: But do you thing it could be a performance problem if I run this program in production ?

Comment: Future.sequence creates a dependency between your two tasks.

Comment: If it's not tail-recursive, it will eventually crash with a stack overflow. You can check by marking the method with `@tailrec`. I did, and scalac complains that it cannot make the method tail-recursive. So you better change it to a loop. Or: scalaz contains a complicated construction with some trampoline that might help you keeping the functional code, but I've never looked at it (for long enough to understand it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using either java's [scheduled executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to schedule tasks with fixed interval. Or you can use Akka if you need communication between this tasks. 
BTW this code does what you ask:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

/**
  * Created by hibou on 13/02/16.
  */
object MyFuture {
  def task1(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("doing job 1")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }

  def task2(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("doing job 2")
    Thread.sleep(500)
  }

  def loopTask1(): Future[Unit] = {
    task1.flatMap(_ => loopTask1())
  }

   def loopTask2(): Future[Unit] = {
    task2.flatMap(_ => loopTask2())
  }

  def infiniteLoop(): Future[Unit] = {
    Future.sequence(List(loopTask1(), loopTask2())).map(_ => ())
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Await.ready(infiniteLoop(), Duration.Inf)
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code does exactly what I want. BTW, what do you think about the recursive call? Do I need to replace by `while(true)` to have better performance and prevent stack overflown ?

Comment: Well, you can either create two threads and put while(true) {...} inside them, or better yet, use "scheduled executor" which will consume less resources for running periodic tasks. But for two tasks it does not matter much. And you will not caught stackoverflow here, because code inside flatMap will run asychronously (imagine that it could run on another thread with its own stack). Except that you can catch simple memory leak, which depends on flatMap implementation, so for this task, you'd rather use foreach or onComplete instead of flatMap

Comment: side note: flatMap on future hide throwables! add a `.recover` (or something else?) to do something with errors.